# How can I refresh a portion of a page with selenium by rerunning javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

The page has a hard coded limit set to 25. This dynamic portion of the page seems to be generated by a javascript called qmodloader.js which eventually calls trades.js

The page is https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=enb

I found this section defining the script

```
<script
id="qmod"
type='application/javascript'
data-qmod-wmid='101020'
data-qmod-env="app"
src="https://qmod.quotemedia.com/js/qmodLoader.js"
></script>
```

qmodLoader.js seems to take window as an input argument

```
(function (window) {
 'use strict';
var qMod = {};
var qmLoader = {};
var qmodScriptEl = document.getElementById('qmod') || console.log('QMOD: Error. Unable to find QMOD Script ID.');
var wmid = qmodScriptEl.getAttribute('data-qmod-wmid') || console.log('QMOD: Error. Unable to find Webmaster ID on, QMOD Script ID.');
var qTools = document.getElementsByClassName('qtool') || console.log('QMOD: Error. No QMOD tools found.');

var qmodVersion = qmodScriptEl.getAttribute('data-qmod-version') || 'v1.18.0';
var qModVersionType = testVersion(qmodVersion);
.....
```

trades.js  has the api end point as below.  There the limit is 50 which is more what I would like

```
apiEndPoints:[{name:"getRecentTradesBySymbol.json",params:{symbol:"GOOGL",tradeIndDesc:"true",limit:50,timezone:!0,tradesummary:!0,tradeExchangeName:!0}},
          {name:"getQuotes.json",params:{symbols:"GOOGL",afterhours:!0,timezone:!0,premarket:!0,currencyInd:!0,countryInd:!0,marketstatus:!0}}]
```

and the hard coded values in the page are at div  class="qtool" and are data-qmod-params='{ "symbol" : "ENB", "limit" : 25 }'

In selenium I did the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
driver.get("https://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=ENB")
wnd = driver.current_window_handle
grab_script = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="qmod"]""").text
driver.execute_script(grab_script,wnd)
```

This was just to try to get the script to reload as an initial test before I start trying to use js to alter the params in the page.  Sadly this is not working.  I am currently getting the following error:

```
/home/stillFoolish/PycharmProjects/WStest/venv/bin/python /home/stillFoolish/PycharmProjects/WStest/test/Test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stillFoolish/PycharmProjects/WStest/test/Test1.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.execute_script(grab_script,"wnd")
  File "/home/stillFoolish/PycharmProjects/WStest/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/stillFoolish/PycharmProjects/WStest/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/stillFoolish/PycharmProjects/WStest/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid type: map, expected a string at line 1 column 28
```

Okay I have corrected the code above as indicated by Y.Berrama.   I no longer have the errors and it runs to completion however the portion of the page I was hoping to reload did not change.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to reload the script? Are you trying to get the next page of values? Are trying to load a new symbol?

Comment: Yes.  I'm trying to refresh without loading the whole page as it loads so slowly.  TBH if I could just pull the data directly would be the easiest but that seems a bit beyond my skill set

Comment: Page is loading properly.I don't see any problem.However why don't you use `driver.refresh()` to reload the page?

Comment: driver.execute_script need a string as parameter and you're passing a selenium object instead. Try to add .text for find _element_by_xpath as follow : `grab_script =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="qmod"]""").text` and then cast grap_script as str

Comment: I don't want to wait for the whole page to load.  Sometimes it is quick and sometimes it take a long time.  When it is stalling I see lots of google adds being loaded. All I'm after is the historical tsx trade data. @KunduK

Comment: @Y.Berrama      ahha.  Yes, thankyou.  I've just been staring at it too long.   Now that is passing with no errors.  Did not reload the data as I had hoped however.  Need to think that through further.